# Type annotation/hint for index in pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

I am trying to add type annotations/hints in a Python script for running [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) checks. I have a `pandas.DataFrame` object, which I [iterate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) like this:

```py
someTable: pandas.DataFrame = pandas.DataFrame()

# ...
# adding some data to someTable
# ...

for index, row in someTable.iterrows():
    #reveal_type(index)
    print(type(index))
    print(index + 1)
```

If I run this script, here's what I get:

```sh
$ python ./some.py
<class 'int'>
2
<class 'int'>
3
```

And if I check it with `mypy`, then it reports errors:

```sh
$ mypy ./some.py
some.py:32: note: Revealed type is "Union[typing.Hashable, None]"
some.py:34: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Hashable" and "int")
some.py:34: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
some.py:34: note: Left operand is of type "Optional[Hashable]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

As I understand, `mypy` sees the `index` as `Union[typing.Hashable, None]`, which is not `int`, and so `index + 1` looks like an error to it. How and where should I then annotate/hint it to satisfy `mypy`?

I tried this:

```py
index: int
for index, row in someTable.iterrows():
    # ...
```

but that results in:

```sh
$ mypy ./some.py
some.py:32: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Hashable]", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hint `index` as `Optional[int]`, but then `x + 1` won't type check.

I'm not sure where `Union[typing.Hashable, None]` comes from; `iterrows` itself returns an `Iterable[tuple[Hashable, Series]]`. But it seems like you can safely assert that if `index` is assigned a value, then it will not be `None`.

```
index: Optional[int]
for index, row in someTable.iterrows():
    index = typing.cast(int, index)
    print(index + 1)
```

(Is the `Union` supposed to reflect the possibility of the iterable raising `StopIteration`? That doesn't seem right, as a function that raises an exception doesn't return `None`; it doesn't return *at all*.)

Comment: Adding `index: Optional[int]` gave me `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Hashable]", variable has type "Optional[int]")`. If this works for you, then I must have a different types package installed. And indeed, I had `data-science-types`, which I now uninstalled and installed `pandas-stubs` instead. Now `index: Optional[int]` is still causing an error but it is actually not needed so I removed it, while `typing.cast()` is needed as with it being present `mypy` is happy now, and so am I. Thank you!

Comment: ...actually, adding `typing.cast()` resolves the issue even having `data-science-types` package - I re-installed it back and uninstalled `pandas-stubs` just to check - so what I was missing is this type casting. I actually did naively try `int(index)`, but that failed, and I didn't research more on that.